# Package missing in hibernate source

Tags: hibernate

I need to create a test for hibernate, so I done a fork of hibernate.

I opened source file in Intellij.
When I try to run a test I get:

> Error:(35, 42) java: package org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.xml.jaxb does
>   not exist

I use openjdk 8 and gradle.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

seem ok.... but still same error...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some folders and run the build plugins to generate code.

See https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ContributingToHibernateUsingIntelliJ for all steps.

> run ./gradlew idea from the command line and open the project in
> IntelliJ IDEA. Note that you will need to add the generated source
> folders (apt, antlr, ...). see the Annotation processor section for
> more info.

---

> **Annotation Processors**
>
> It's currently recommended to explicitly disable
> the annotation processors in IntelliJ; from the project settings,
> "Java Compiler", make sure that
>
> "-proc:none" is used as option to javac raise the maximum heap size
> Then in the module settings:
>
> for hibernate-core module add these source folders:
> target/generated-src/jaxb/main
>
> target/generated-src/logging/main
>
> target/generated-src/antlr/main
>
> for hibernate-entitymanager, add:
> target/generated-src/jpamodelgen/test

Comment: have same issue